# Drupal automagically changing password hash

Tags: 7, users

This issue happened on my  localhost machine while in development but I thought nothing of it since I had multiple drupal projects and was jumping to one another constantly - I figure it was cookies or what not and was constantly resetting my passwords. However I recently went into production and this issue is still occuring.

I have a new drupal site for which I created 2 new users for testing purposes. I realized that after 24 hours or so, the login credentials for these users would not work and I would get :

> Sorry, unrecognized username or password. Have you forgotten your password?

I use these accounts to log in via browsers other than my main one and test the user interface of my production site. After each use I make sure I logout.

I made sure to configure the  $cookie_domain in my settings.php and chmod the file properly but the issue still occurs.

Recently I started tracking the hashes in the user table and low and behold they are magically changing without any human intervention ! What can be causing that ?

Oddly enough, this issue does not happen with the admin account (#1) for which I have yet to logout, and another account which was created but never used. In both cases user_check_password() returns true.

Clearing cache does nothing.

I am running the latest core with latest version of all contrib. modules.
I use SSL everywhere
I have APC and memcache running.
I use a mix of MongoDB and MySQL

Comment: "they are magically changing without any human intervention " - no, they are not. There is no magic. Ho accesses your database or page when this happens? IP logged? Because that looks like malicious attack, or some bad joke. Anyway, security audit looks like a thing you should get.

Comment: Your setup too complex debug IMO. Try turning off Memcache. Also, look for any snippets that call `user_save()`.

Comment: Nice catch Ayesh, it was indeed related to user_save(). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with my own code.

I would load the user object every day to perform operations and change some fields value.

Instead of just passing the new fields as the second argument of user_save(), I would pass the newly changed user object cast as an array, which was causing my password hash to be re-hashed on every call of this function.